# How can I automate correcting broken up words?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I have copy-pasted a large text into InDesign. The problem is that a lot of words got broken up, so for example a text might look like this:

> As descri bed below, we collect i nformation from and abou t the computers, phones, connected TVs and other web-conn ected devices you use that integrate with our Products, and we c ombi ne this information across different devices you use. For example, we use information collected about your use of our Products on your phone to better per sonalize the content (including ads) or fe atures you see when you use our P roducts on another device, such as your laptop or table t, or to measure whether you took an action in r esponse to an ad we showed you on your phone on a differ ent device.

Most words are correct but many are broken up in random parts. When I use 'Check spelling' it will recognise many of these words (because the word "nformation" doesn't exist). Is there a way (with or without a script or GREP expression) to 'repair' these words for example by letting 'Spelling' check for the words and looking for the missing bits next to it?
Autocorrect is turned on but doesn't seem to do anything, plus I don't think it would be able to repair a word like "c ombi ne" because it might not see this as "combine" plus it could leave the "c" and "ne" left over.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you reveal the original text (=before you have copied it to somewhere)? It can have something detectable and removable which isn't the ordinary space.

Comment: This is the link to one of the files that messes up: https://autoriteitpersoonsgegevens.nl/sites/default/files/downloads/pb/pb_20090324_definitieve_bevindingen_zikle.pdf

Comment: As far as I am aware, no such tool exists. There's simply too much variation and there's no way to tell what is a misspelling or what is a word remnant. I think you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess:

You haven't opened the PDF in Adobe Reader nor Acrobat, but in some other PDF reader or web browser. The PDF actually has a zillion separate text objects, even a single line can have several of them. Division points can be in the middle of a word. You can see it if you open one page, say page 2 in Illustrator:

[image]

The application from which you copied the text inserts a space to every border between separate text objects on the same line. Adobe Reader and Acrobat  allow continuous text copying from actually separate text objects. They insert nothing. Try them.

**Not asked**, but In Illustrator there's an old trick to fix split text: Select all text objects, copy them to the clipboard, take the text tool, click & drag a new text frame, paste. The new text area has the text without split words. Unfortunately paragraphs are also combined to one.

Comment: I used Microsoft Edge I believe. So, if you open the file with Adobe Reader or Acrobat, do those spaces disappear? I don't have either right now but I could get one.

Comment: @SilliusSoddus I tried both and with the text selection tool the text was copied without extra spaces. It was perfect when pasted to an InD text object. There are also other PDF readers and web browsers to try. All of them do not make crap. Web browser Opera let me copy text from that PDF faultlessly.

Comment: @SilliusSoddus (an opinion) generally there's nothing in Microsoft's products which is designed to make Adobe's programs look out useful.